# Post doctoral while working on self employed job

Tags: ethics, postdocs, university, legal-issues, biotechnology

I am in need to know if there is a provision wherein I could do a post-doctorate in the USA for a year or two, while I am owning my own Biotechnology firm back in my home country?

Answer (score 2):

This is a complex issue with a lot of variables. If your post-doc is for work completely unrelated to the work of the company then there is probably no serious issue as long as you faithfully complete the required work.

However, you will also face several issues if there is some relationship. For example, will you have conflicts of interest between the two aspects? That would make it hard-to-impossible to carry on. Likewise, are there intellectual property issues? In other words, is it possible that you will learn something in the post-doc that is, for contractual or other reasons, off-limits to your company. There may be other issues as well if there is any overlap.

For issues such as these, both the post-doc project PI and a lawyer should be consulted.

Comment: No My firm has nothing to do with the academic project and there is no common interest, one is on plants and other on animal and food or agriculture products and research. My firm is not self-owned but a partnership of recent origin. As I wasn't finding opportunities in academic, I had to decide to be self-employed. However, after two year struggle, I received some notable reputation in terms of publications from my PhD work that i think would help me in the academic expeirence.

Comment: We have no issues in the firm documentation that prevent the partners from going for a post-doc. but I was concerned if the financial aid for post-doc is government aided, do they have any restrictions that prevent the candidate from having alternate income unless he is fails to fulfill the work requirements of post doc?

Comment: @AvinashKumar, I doubt there are any financial restrictions for a post-doc, unlike for some scholarships. It is a job like many others.

Comment: Thank you very much Dr. Buffy. It sounds like a good news to me. I am glad I could discuss this matter here at academia with you.